# Is it possible to prevent two functions from commuting?

Tags: sorting, operators, order

I have an expression of the following type:

```
x f[a] g[b]
```

where `x` is a number but `f[a]` and `g[b]` are non-commuting functions. Is it possible to prevent `f` and `g` from commuting without influencing the behavior of `x`?

Comment: Arrest them if they use the HOV lane?

Answer (score 1):

Your example works out of the box in [NCAlgebra](https://www.github.com/NCAlgebra/NC).

```
fun1 = x1 f[a]
fun2 = x2 g[a]
fun1 ** fun2
```

returns

> x1 x2 f[a] ** g[a]

Things to note, NCAlgebra, by default, treats lower case letters from `a` through `z` as noncommutative symbols. So in your example, `x1` and `x2` are commutative, and factor out of the noncommutative product. It also treats a function as noncommutative if its arguments are noncommutative symbols. So

```
fun1 = x1 F[a]
fun2 = x2 G[a]
fun1 ** fun2
```

would also work.

P.S.: We are in the process of updating NCAlgebra so you might want to try our latest beta version from [here](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/tree/v6.0.0), which you can install as a paclet.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to proceed the function product algebra in the tensor product sense as an ordered alebra over the complex number field is to use the ordinary TensorProduct, that has the linear operations on board. If  one wants to get rid of the clumsy notation,  Use CenterDot as Output

```
\[Phi][x]\[TensorProduct] (g[x] + 3 h[x]) // 
   TensorExpand) /. {TensorProduct -> CenterDot}

ϕ [ x ] · g [ x ] + 3 ⁢ ϕ [ x ] · h [ x ]
```

Remark: I have copied this expression from Mathematica as MathXML. This browser interface renders the expression as above in the representation window, but complains about non formatted code. Copy the expression from the output window  back to the editor window instead of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like `x f[a] g[b]` is interpreted as `Times[...]`, and regular multiplication (aka Times) is assumed to be commutative. There is a built-in symbol to represent non-commutative multiplication: `NonCommutativeMultiply` which uses `**` as its infix form.

Having said that, I don't really understand the rest of your question, so I don't know how to help you further.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! What I meant is that `x f[a] g[b] = f[a] x g[b] = f[a] g[b] x`. But I think your answer should be enough for my purposes.

Comment: Actually I am not sure it does. Imagine I have two functions `fun1=x1 f[a]` and `fun2=x2 g[a]`. I would like to have the result of the (non-commutative) multiplication be given as: `fun1**fun2=x1 x2 f[a]**g[b]`. Is that possible with `**` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still confused. I think I'd need to see your actual functions and some test cases that specify the desired behavior.

Comment: The comment above is an actual piece of code I have. I want to multiply `fun1` and `fun2` such that only `f[a]` and `g[b]` do not commute.

Comment: If it is still unclear, let me know where is your doubt.

Comment: So, you want to combine commutative multiplication with non-commutative multiplication?

Comment: Does the resulting computation need to be non-commutative, or are you just wanting the display of the expression to be in a particular order?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The result needs to be non-commutative.